# Being vs beings

Tags: history-of-philosophy, existentialism, heidegger

I'm reading a book of Martin Heidegger in which i found the term 'being' and 'beings'
I tried to know more about it but there is not much reference on internet.. Please explain both the term according to Heidegger

Comment: beings is no the plural of being?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises no